# How to dynamically assign an id to an image

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dynamic

```
var intFields = 0;
var maxFields = 10;
function addElement() {
    "use strict";
    var i, intVal, contentID, newTBDiv, message = null;
    intVal = document.getElementById('add').value;
    contentID = document.getElementById('content');
    message = document.getElementById('message');
    if (intFields !== 0) {
        for (i = 1; i <= intFields; i++) {
            contentID.removeChild(document.getElementById('strText' + i));
        }
        intFields = 0;
    }
    if (intVal <= maxFields) {
        for (i = 1; i <= intVal; i++) {
            intFields = i;
            newTBDiv = document.createElement('div');
            newTBDiv.setAttribute('id', 'strText' + intFields);
            newTBDiv.innerHTML = "<input placeholder='recipient" + intFields + "@email.com' type='text' name='" + intFields + "'/><a href='javascript:removeElement();'><img id='strImg + " + intFields + "' src='images/minus.png' alt='Add A Field'/></a><input type='text' value='" + newTBDiv.id + "'/>";
            contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);
            message.innerHTML = "Successfully added " + intFields + " fields.";
        }
    } else {
        for (i = 1; i <= maxFields; i++) {
            intFields = i;
            newTBDiv = document.createElement('div');
            newTBDiv.setAttribute('id', 'strText' + intFields);
            newTBDiv.innerHTML = "<input placeholder='recipient" + intFields + "@email.com' type='text' name='" + intFields + "'/><a href='javascript:removeElement();'><img id='strImg + " + intFields + "' src='images/minus.png' alt='Add A Field'/></a><input type='text' value='" + newTBDiv.id + "'/>";
            contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);
            message.innerHTML = "Unable to create more than 10 receipient fields!";
        }
    }
}
```

My script here dynamically adds up to 10 fields where users will be able to enter an email address and to the right of the text box i add an image of a minus sign that calls another script. I'm having trouble working out how to assign and keep track of the minus signs. I need to be able to have the minus sign script's recognize the text box it is by and remove it. I can write the remove script easily enough but I'm unsure of how to tell the image which text box to remove. Any help, suggestions, or comments are greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Nick S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to the field called minus and then check through like that. I would suggest using jquery for this.

To add the class

```
$("#element").addClass("minus");
```

To remove all elements with that class

```
$("body input").each(function (i) { 
    if($(this).attr("class") == "minus"){
       $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The two best options, imo, would be 1) DOM-traversal, or 2) manipulating ID fragments.

Under the first way, you would pass a reference to the element where the event takes place (the minus sign) and then navigate the DOM from there to the get the appropriate text box (in jQuery you could use `$(this).prev()`, for example).

Under the second way, you would assign a prefix or a suffix to the ID of the triggering element (the minus sign), and the same prefix or suffix to the target element (the text box).  You can then (again) generate the appropriate ID for your target element by simple string manipulation of the ID from the triggering element.

Is that sufficient to get you started?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class to the field and the same class to the minus sign.

So add this right after the setAttribute id,

```
newTBDiv.setAttribute('class', 'field' + intFields);
```

then just remove any elements that have that class.